# Why doesn't git merge-base report last merge point?

Tags: git, git-merge

We see unexpected conflicts on a feature branch during 2nd catchup merge with master.  During investigation, I used git merge-base expecting to find latest merge point between the branches but found an earlier and I suspect this results in our unexpected conflicts.

**Questions**

- What did we do wrong to hit this problem?
- Can we specify the merge-base to use in a merge command?
- Can someone explain why we might be seeing an earlier merge point as base?

**Back Story / history of branch master relationship**

- feature branch created from master
- changes on master (product src, systest src)
- changes on feature (product src)
- **nov29 catchup merge** from master to feature results in (product src, systest src) changes applied to feature
- changes on master (product src, systest src)
- changes on feature (product src)
- catchup merge from master to feature shows conflict on systest src

  - merge base appears to be nov15 not previous catchup merge
- git merge-base master feature results in nov15 commit not **nov29 catchup merge**

Comment: After much investigation user error seems the most likely case even though this user seems unlikely to have committed such an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order:

1. I don't know, but the clues will be in the output of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --boundary master...feature`.  The `--graph` shows the graph; `master...feature` selects all commits that are on either branch but not both (i.e., removes merge bases); `--boundary` puts back the first-removed commits (i.e., the merge bases); and `--decorate --oneline` presents the graph in a nicer viewing format.
2. No, Git always computes the merge base(s) on its own, from the graph.
3. Because that/those is/are the merge base(s), based on the graph.

There are in fact two key items above: **the graph dictates all** and **there may be more than one merge base** (use `git merge-base --all` to see *all* of them, when there are more than one).  In the case of multiple bases, the `-s recursive` default merge strategy uses all of them, while the `-s resolve` merge strategy picks one, arbitrarily.  Usually there is only one anyway so that this makes no difference, and when there *is* more than one, in the ideal case, all merge bases would produce the same result, so that `-s recursive` amounts to "just checking".

#### Background

Technically, the merge base is defined by the "lowest common ancestor" or LCA of the DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).  (The term "lowest" comes about because computer scientists draw their trees upside down.)  In a DAG there may be more than one equally-low common ancestor, and this is when multiple merge bases occur; in Git, this can happen only if there are "criss-cross merges", where you do:

```
git checkout main; git merge sub
git checkout sub; git merge main
```

so that both branches are merged into each other.

For more on DAGs and LCAs, see Chapter 2 of [this very drafty draft](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  this is really strange.  I'm only seeing one merge-base even when I use --all.  It almost looks like the nov29 merge wasn't really a merge even though I'm told by the user that merge was used.   I'm going to have call this as user-error.  Not sure what happened between merge command and commit but something had to otherwise, I'd see the graph and nov29 commit would have two parent.